# Windows font rasterization, blackbox bug?

Tags: windows, fonts, truetype, rasterizing

I abandoned my efforts to rasterize TTF on my own since I don't want to do hinting, so I turned to Windows's method... And I think I found a bug.

I used Windows's **DrawText** function and in the left column are **GLYPHMETRICS** structures loaded with **GetGlyphOutline**:

```
    SetRect(&rect, 10,0,5,5);
    SetTextColor(glyph_hdc, RGB(255,0,0));
    DrawText(glyph_hdc, TEXT("A"), -1,&rect, DT_NOCLIP);
    ...
    SetRect(&rect, 70,0,5,5);
    SetTextColor(glyph_hdc, RGB(255,0,0));
    DrawText(glyph_hdc, TEXT("!"), -1,&rect, DT_NOCLIP);


GetGlyphOutlineA(glyph_hdc, ascii_code, GGO_BITMAP, &glyph_metric_A, 10000, win_bitmap, &m2);
```

I used gray 2x1 rectangles in Adobe Illustrator to measure distances...
[image]

I hope that the picture illustrates well the apparent bug: The BlackBoxX and BlackBoxY should be [enclosing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/ns-wingdi-glyphmetrics) the glyph. Do you think that this is an internal bug? Do you know how to correct for this? It seems like the black box does not account for hinting.

Comment: remember to take glyph lsb (found in hmtx) and rsb (effectively quad size - glyph maxx) into consideration.

Comment: How is it relevant? gmBlackBoxX: The width of the smallest rectangle that completely encloses the glyph (its black box). (msdn docs)

Comment: fair point. Looking at industry-standard code that works with this (e.g. Cairo's https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/third_party/cairo/+/master/src/cairo-win32-font.c#952), is scaling relevant to you?

Comment: Practically, I don't think it ever matters since you probably only care about the two coordinate systems (blue and red dots) + the advancement... The widths of glyphs are bounded so you can use the max value. It might matter if you want to pack the glyphs close together.. personally, I'm not planning on that so...

Comment: When it comes to scaling, I don't know what you mean... I only found out from [here](https://support.microsoft.com/es-py/help/200262/how-to-fit-text-in-a-rectangle) that the glyph height is a slave of the cell height, because of the hinting process.

Comment: On a sidenote, for opentype and opentype tech questions, SO is an unreliable source of answers. You probably want to also post this over on the https://typedrawers.com tech subforum (where all the big name foundry people hang out, including MS folks)

Comment: Ok, I will but where exactly? So far I posted it [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/feedback/issues/2148).

Comment: the font technilogy subforum. Also worth putting the links to other places you asked in your question, in case font folks more usually work in either of those places and feel like answering it there makes more sense than answering it here.